# NextAuth JS Connecting to Discord

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm trying to use next-auth to connect to Discord

Code Present in
`pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js`

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord'


const scopes = ['identify'].join(' ')


export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    DiscordProvider({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {params: {scope: scopes}},
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      if (account.provider != 'discord' && !user.id){
        return
      }
      console.log("================================")
      console.log("User: ", user, "\nAccount: ", account, "\nProfile: ", profile, "\nEmail: ", email, "\nCredentials: ", credentials)
      console.log("================================")
      return true
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      return session
    },
  }
})
```

Now I'm using next-auth for my websites existing users to link their discord account
While in callback I'm able to get the discord details I've no way to identify which existing user has linked their account in this piece of code..

I've tried `getSession` but it returns `null` also tried for session callback but no luck.
Please guide me on this issue.
I'm still new to it

**UPDATE:**
On front-end before calling `signIn('discord')` I did

```js
const {data: session, update} = useSession();
update({...session, user: {...session.user}, customField: 'XYZ'})
console.log("UPDATED SESSION", session)
```

and In jwt callback I'm able to see that customField but it doesn't get updated in front-end...

Thank you